# Photometry data from Gaia

Tags: gaia, light-curve

I am trying to get data from Gaia. Especially for Cepheids or RR Lyrae. On Gaia websites it say they have released some of the data however I cannot find it. I am looking for two columns with time and magnitude(light curve).

Thanks for help

Comment: In such cases it's smart to link the link you're talking about.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04269 is the paper describing the release of Gaia DR1 Cepheid and RR Lyrae data.